# Django use AWS sand mail, "SESAddressNotVerifiedError: 400 Email address is not verified."

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I use django and AWS to send mail.
I have moved my account out of sandbox.

```
Your account has also been moved out of the sandbox
```

I use `boto` and `django-ses`.
My setting.py is

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '************************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '****************************************'
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'us-west-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
```

And view.py is

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail import send_mail
Megti = '*********'
Megco = '*********'
send_mail(
    Megti,
    Megco,
    'XXXX@XXXXXX.com', [aproduct.commail],
    fail_silently=False)
```

I get error:

```
SESAddressNotVerifiedError at /success/success
SESAddressNotVerifiedError: 400 Email address is not verified.
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
    <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>
    <Message>Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: XXXX@XXXXXX.com</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>3cdc4a07-6523-11e7-b493-1d79005a6fdc</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: did you solve? i want send email from verified email address to other email address

Comment: Try this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Answer (score 0):

When you move out of sandbox, only the recipients' email address need not have to be verified but the `Sender's` email has to be verified.

[Amazon SES Email Sending Errors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ses-errors.html)

> You are trying to send email from an email address or domain that you
>   have not verified with Amazon SES. This error could apply to the
>   "From", "Source", "Sender", or "Return-Path" address.

Comment: tks, if I want to send mail to "not verified with Amazon SES", what can I do?

Comment: @felixkuo Sender mail has to be verified always. If you are in sandbox, you cannot send email to unverified email address. If you are out sandbox, you can send mail to unverified email address.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your SES is in sandbox mode.

> To help prevent fraud and abuse, and to help protect your reputation
>   as a sender. We place all new accounts in the **Amazon SES sandbox**.
>
> - You can only send mail to verified email addresses and domains, or to
>     the Amazon SES mailbox simulator.
> - You can only send mail from verified email addresses and domains.

Visit [remove from the Amazon SES sandbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) to get out sandbox by contacting support.